# How to yield results in table without duplicate result in Cypher?

Tags: cypher

Say I have node X that links to node A1, A2, A3 with edge A, node B1, B2 with edge B, and node C1 with edge C. I want to have a query like this:

```sql
match (x)-[:A]->(a) 
match (x)<-[:B]-(b) 
match (x)-[:C]-(c) 
where x.name="X" 
return a.name,b.name,c.name
```

And the result is this table:

| a.name | b.name | c.name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | B1 | C1 |
| A2 | B2 |  |
| A3 |  |  |

Not a table of 6 combinations. Is that possible? The Neo4j Cypher Manual of [`RETURN`](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/return/) isn't useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do this, with the advantage over Nathan's answer that it also yields a result in case some of the edge types are missing, e.g. when there is no B edge.

```
MATCH (x) WHERE x.name = 'X'
WITH x,
     [(x)-[:A]->(a) | a] AS allAs,
     [(x)<-[:B]-(b) | b] AS allBs,
     [(x)-[:C]-(c) | c] AS allCs
WITH x, allAs, allBs, allCs, apoc.coll.max([size(allAs), size(allBs), size(allCs)]) as maxSize
UNWIND range(0, maxSize -1) as index
RETURN allAs[index].name as A, allBs[index].name as B, allCs[index].name as C
```

Answer (score 1):

This will return each node matched with a, b, and c in exactly one row of the output.

```
match (x)-[:A]->(a) 
where x.name="X" 
WITH x, collect(a) as allAs
match (x)<-[:B]-(b) 
WITH x, allAs, collect(b) as allBs
match (x)-[:C]-(c) 
WITH x, allAs, allBs, collect(c) as allCs
WITH x, allAs, allBs, allCs, apoc.coll.max([size(allAs), size(allBs), size(allCs)]) as maxSize
UNWIND range(0, maxSize -1) as index
RETURN allAs[index].name as A, allBs[index].name as B, allCs[index].name as C
```

Comment: I just added an alternative, with less MATCHes , and an advantage.